# Is there a way to read the first word of all line from a file with ReGex?

Tags: python, regex, string, file, parsing

I'm looking at any txt file to parse specific information. The information is the name of the room, coordinates_x, and coordinates_y. The name of the room can be any string name (`abc`, `6a7b8c`, `_test1n6_`, etc) and excludes a '#' because then it will be part of my error management. To explain the txt file more, I want to ignore always the first line, and after the first line, it is the room that is being made in the x and y coordinates (e.g `2 5 0` has a room called `2` with coordinates (5, 0) ). I'm not getting all my necessary line strings from the file that I need. For example, I only get the ones that starts with any character without, but also getting strings that I don't really need for now. I just started learning Regex a day ago, so bear with me please :).

I'm using the website regexr to visualize and see the output search doing. It is working fantastic, but the more I think of the error checking, the more complicated my regex becomes.

This is my current Regex:

```
\S+(\w+[0-9]) | \s+\w*[A-Z]
```

and the txt file is this:

```
3
2 5 0
##start
0 1 2
##end
1 9 2
3 5 4
######################
###lol123
###1234124
#111shouldnotread#~!~
6ajhk 888 888 
D_c7 10 10
Enz4 11 11
Maf9 15 15
Eex5 18 18
U_e6 21 21
Nip5 25 25
Gw_5 28 28
Vio7 31 31
His7 34 34
Exh6 37 37
Iq_8 42 42
Qky2 45 45
Tac1 49 49
X__5 51 51
Xlb4 55 55
0-2
0-3
2-1
3-1
2-3
```

Output:

```
888 
888 
D_c7 
Enz4 
Maf9 
Eex5 
U_e6 
Nip5 
Gw_5 
Vio7 
His7 
Exh6 
Iq_8 
Qky2 
Tac1 
X__5 
Xlb4
```

For now, I'm getting all that I want, but not quite there yet. You see, I have some of my rooms, but not the one with `"6ajhk"` which is my room's name and has coordinates of `(888, 888)`. The rest is being handled separately already. Thanks for your time and patience.

Comment: [`^\w+(?= \d+ \d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/PqMTIu/1). Is this what you're trying to do?

Comment: Not quite, the output is partially good because I'm getting most of my rooms (D_c7, Enz4, Maf9 ...) but what I'm not getting is `6ajhk`. The name of the room can be any size of the string, so it can be a long name @WiktorStribiżew and @Ahmed

Comment: Do you just want the name of the room or do you need more data? What exactly do you need that `^\w+(?= \d+ \d+)` does not capture?

Comment: `^(\w{4,}) (\d+) (\d+)` should, see https://regex101.com/r/vZMDVU/2

Comment: How about only the first part of the word @WiktorStribiżew ? It seems good, but it grabs the coordinates of the room as well.

Comment: `^\w{4,}(?=(?: \d+){2})`? https://regex101.com/r/vZMDVU/3

Comment: The `| \s+\w*[A-Z]` part is not matching any text in the test sample, thus, I am suggesting something alternative. It is not very clear what your data is really like. `\S+(\w+[0-9])` is too fragile: `\S+` matches what `\w+` does, and `\w+` only matches last word char from the substring grabbed by `\S+` initially, before backtracking.

Comment: Another idea: match words at the start of a line that are not all digits - `^(?!\d+\b)\w+`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/vZMDVU/4).

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed I’m not anywhere close to my computer at the moment. What I noticed in yours is I need to take out the ‘^’ and it should be fine afterwards. Sorry for the late response

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I will try it out after I come back. Thanks for all of your help and sorry for the late response :)

Comment: @ZeidTisnes If the room name is always at the beginning of the line, you should _not_ get rid of `^`. You just need to use the `MULTILINE` flag.

Comment: Oh I see, I was using the `g` to try your example out @AhmedAbdelhameed

Answer (score 0):

I think that this should do what you want.

```regex
^([^\s#]{4,5}) (\d+) (\d+)
```

See: https://regex101.com/r/Kqakb8/2

Comment: Would you check again? I realized you wanted the coords as well and added them.

Comment: I checked once again thanks to Ahmed. I had to toggle the flag for multiline and it seems to be working too. Also, the grouping helps a lot as well. Thank you for your help :D. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your requirements correctly, this regex seems to do the trick:

```
/^\w*(?!\n)(?=\s)/gm
```

Note that I'm using the multi-line flag `/m`.

You can test it here: https://regexr.com/4arnh

Edit: if you don't want to include single digit room names, you can use:

```
/^\w{2,}(?=[^\S\n])/gm
```

where 2 is the minimum number of characters in a room string. Demo here: https://regexr.com/4arnq

Comment: `(?!\n)(?=\s)` = `(?=[^\S\n])`